# 500 errors after patching Magento 1.9.0 with SUPEE-6285

Tags: magento-1.9, error, patches, supee-6285

Patched Magento with SUPEE-5994 and was successful. After clearing cache and clearing and disabling compilation site worked fine.

I then patched with SUPEE-6285 and whilst indicating it was successful in the ssh console i now can not access either the store or admin. The HTTP error log shows the following...

> PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/html/app/Mage.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/index.php on line 69
>
> PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/app/Mage.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/index.php on line 69

Answer (score 2):

**failed to open stream: Permission denied**

Try to set permissions as following

## for magento 1.5+

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chmod o+w var var/.htaccess app/etc
chmod 550 mage
chmod -R o+w media
```